# What was the age of Balarama during his marriage and what was the age of Revati when she visited Brahmaloka?

Tags: marriage, balarama

[Revati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revati), along with her father [Kakudmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakudmi) went to Brahmaloka. Brahma told the following words to them

> After hearing his words, Lord Brahmā, who is most powerful, laughed loudly and said to Kakudmī: O King, all those whom you may
>   have decided within the core of your heart to accept as your
>   son-in-law have passed away in the course of time.
>       **Twenty-seven catur-yugas have already passed**. Those upon whom you may have decided are now gone, and so are their sons, grandsons and
>   other descendants. You cannot even hear about their names.
>       O King, leave here and offer your daughter to Lord Baladeva, who is still present. He is most powerful. Indeed, He is the Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead, whose plenary portion is Lord Viṣṇu. Your
>   daughter is fit to be given to Him in charity.
>
> [[31-33, Chapter 3, Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/3/)

After hearing Brahma's words, Kakumdi and Revati returned from Brahmaloka. Kakumdmi gave Revati to Balarama

> Thereafter, the King gave his most beautiful daughter in charity to
>   the supremely powerful Baladeva and then retired from worldly life and
>   went to Badarikāśrama to please Nara-Nārāyaṇa.
>
> [[35, Chapter 3, Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/3/)

Since Brahma told that twenty-seven catur-yugas have already passed **on earth**, it is clear that Revati born around Twenty-seven catur-yugas **before** Balarama.

It is also clear that they spent very less time in Brahmaloka. Due to time dilation only, twenty-seven catur-yugas have passed on earth. Thus **Reavti's age is not increased** much (probably at-most one day).

> When Kakudmī arrived there, Lord Brahmā was engaged in hearing musical
>   performances by the Gandharvas and had not a moment to talk with him.
>   Therefore Kakudmī waited, and at the end of the musical performances
>   he offered his obeisances to Lord Brahmā and thus submitted his
>   long-standing desire.
>
> [[30, Chapter 3, Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/3/)

---

Now, if we consider only the ages of Revati and Balarama, irrespective of when they born on earth, who is elder than whom?